# How to embed the Layout in managed package

Tags: managed-package

We have developed the managed app and now its ready to deploy to app exchange market, I want to know that how we can deploy the layout?

In standard page layout we have added the visualforce page and how I can do this in installed org?

Comment: Just add your layout in your app package.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: same as you add other components you can also add Page layout.  Did you don't find the option to add page layout.

Comment: @TusharSharma I can see that and added to the package

Answer (score 0):

To verify your question, I created an unmanaged package and added a custom object to the package. As a result, salesforce automatically included following components

1. List View
2. Custom Fields
3. Validation Rule
4. Standard Page layout (Default)
5. Visualforce Pages, if included in the layout

It will follow the same behavior for manage package as well.

> Update -

You will have to explicitly add Standard Page Layout for standard Objects. However it will automatically include related page

> Page layout ->    Actions, custom buttons, custom links, s-controls, and
>   Visualforce pages

More Details : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_components_auto_added.htm

Comment: It's about standard layout not custom.

Comment: I am also talking about standard Page Layout, which is automatically created when an object is created.

Comment: Standard objects page layout

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable not to modify standard layout for standard objects and package standard layout.The reason for this may be different customers mmay have different fields set on their standard layout and you don't want to override them with yours.

The best strategy are

1)Add in the set up guide which will teach them how to configure your component in standard page layout for standard object.Make a video tutorial of set up.

2)Provide a custom page layout with inline vf configured and explain customers consequence of using that